How to scale log with zero and node to mark?
\pdfoutput=1
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
% \usepackage[review]{EMNLP2023}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
% table color
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{scalefnt}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{amaranth}{rgb}{0.9, 0.17, 0.31}
\definecolor{americanrose}{rgb}{1.0, 0.01, 0.24}
\definecolor{lightskyblue}{rgb}{0.53, 0.81, 0.98}
\definecolor{limegreen}{rgb}{0.2, 0.8, 0.2}
\definecolor{mossgreen}{rgb}{0.68, 0.87, 0.68}
\definecolor{babyblueeyes}{rgb}{0.63, 0.79, 0.95}
\definecolor{babyblue}{rgb}{0.54, 0.81, 0.94}
\definecolor{columbiablue}{rgb}{0.61, 0.87, 1.0}
\definecolor{brightlavender}{rgb}{0.75, 0.58, 0.89}
\definecolor{brightube}{rgb}{0.82, 0.62, 0.91}
\definecolor{brilliantlavender}{rgb}{0.96, 0.73, 1.0}
\definecolor{beige}{rgb}{0.96, 0.96, 0.86}
\definecolor{bananamania}{rgb}{0.98, 0.91, 0.71}
\definecolor{apricot}{rgb}{0.98, 0.81, 0.69}

\begin{document}
{\scalefont{0.5}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            title={\tiny Boolq},
            xlabel={Accuracy},
            ylabel={Soft prompt norm},
            width=0.275\textwidth,
            ymajorgrids=true,
            xmajorgrids=true,
            % nodes near coords,
            ytick={0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000},
            ytick align=outside,
            xtick align=outside,
            xtick pos=left,
            ytick pos=left,
            grid style={Gray!10},
            ymode=log,
            tickwidth=1pt,
            mark size=1pt,
        ]
        \addplot[line width=1pt, only marks] coordinates {
        (0., 0.) (21.8, 56.4) (61.2, 181.6) (66.2, 2178.6) (75.5, 613901) (75.7, 1011692)
        };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}


The above Latex results are as follows. I would like to mark 0 together like the symlog in matplotlib as below, and I would like to mark node as well.


Welcome. // Mathematically you can‘t as there is no zero on the logarithmic axis. It doesn’t make sense, it doesn’t convey any useful information. You can approximate „zero“ by replacing (0,0) by a small enough value, like (0,.1) or (0,.0001) and chose xmin and ymin accordingly … but: what is small enough? As I said, it doesn’t convey useful information in the semilog or loglog world.
